# Consuming ETW events into a socket/named pipe

Tags: windows, etw

I have an application which creates ETW events.
So far, I consumed its events using the real-time logger and the file logger.

I was wondering - Is it possible to consume the event into an open socket/named pipe?

Note that consuming the ETW using logman's remote machine is not what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance,

Tal.